# T-SQL - Get last 30 Rows for eacht ID

Tags: sql, t-sql

how can i get the last 30 rows in a month for each employee? i have a table with evaluations for each employee.

```sql
SELECT
  Date,
  Month,
  Team,
  Employee_ID,
  Evaluation_Score,
  Evaluation_Case_Number
From X
Where month = @month
Order by date desc
```

This is what i got, but i only want to see the last 30 Evaluation Scores (or less, if they don't have that many)  for the declared month.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: SELECT TOP, or SELECT LIMIT should help you.  See the guide.

Comment: Tried this one, but it only shows 30 rows overall. What i need ist <=30 rows for Month x for every employee.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Aside: I'm guessing that you won't want the "top" 30 rows for Angie in August after you have accumulated more than one year's data. What happens on August 1st when it pulls one row from this year, 22 from last year and 7 from the year before that? Is that what you want?

Comment: @NewbieSQL_Germany If you think that one of the answers is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`. Something like this:

```
select x.*
from (select x.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from x
      where month = @month
     ) x
where seqnum <= 30;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement:

```sql
SELECT TOP(30)
  Date,
  Month,
  Team,
  Employee_ID,
  Evaluation_Score,
  Evaluation_Case_Number

From X

Where month = @month

Order by date desc
```

This will help you to limit the number of returned rows.